# Chef - Get IP addresses of provisioning nodes

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

**What would be the best approach to get the IP address of nodes I provision with a `machine` resource ?**

We have two approaches in mind.

- Use `search` function like this (a bit ugly):

  ```
  machines = Hash.new
  machine_names.each do |machine_name|
      s = search(:node, "fqdn:#{machine_name}",
        :filter_result => {'ip' => [ 'ipaddress' ] }
      ).each do |result|
      machines[machine_name] = result['ip']
     end
  end
  ```

which is a bit ugly, or trying to play with node attributes:

- Use `ohai`  to get the IP address **directly on the node** and **send it back to the provisioner node** (I'd like to see some code accomplishing this).

Comment: I see the `machine` resource returns something here: https://docs.chef.io/resource_machine.html (at the very bottom). What class is it? Can you get an IP address from it? Probably not since the machine wouldn't exist yet. Using `search` seems like the "natural" approach here to me.

Comment: Have you tried just "#{node['ipaddress']}"?

Comment: use node['ipaddress'] as suggested by @Mia